# TextMate: Find in Files seems to have out-of-date cache (maybe because of AckMate?)

Tags: textmate, ack

I have installed AckMate a while ago, and the problem I describe here never happened to me before, so maybe it's because of AckMate...?

Here we go: often when I'm searching inside a project, TextMate finds occurrences of the search pattern in "old versions" of files, meaning it the search pattern has definitely been there once, but isn't anymore! Take a look at the screen:

[image: find in files]

I searched for encoding_name, and it found it, but when opening the file, there it isn't anymore (but it has been there a while ago, I know that).

The same when searching within log files of Rails: I do a `rake log:clear`, but it still finds stuff within the log files, but when opening them, they are empty!

What's happening? Is it because of AckMate, maybe? I don't know a lot about it, I just installed it because it was mentioned to be a very nice plugin, and in fact, it is! I also installed PeepOpen, but I don't suspect it to have anything to do with this.

Thanks, for help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know whether this is related, but it may have something to do with file handles, see here:

[Rails doesn't write to development.log file anymore as soon as I save it from another location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783109/rails-doesnt-write-to-development-log-file-anymore-as-soon-as-i-save-it-from-an)