# Rails doesn't write to development.log file anymore as soon as I save it from another location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, textmate

I'm facing a really strange problem. When I start `rails s`, Rails logs as expected to log/development.log file.

As soon as I open it in an editor (e.g. Vi, TextMate) and save it from there, Rails doesn't write to it anymore! I have to restart the server, and then it works again.

This is really strange, it seems like Vi/TextMate "steals" the right to write the file, and only a restart of the Rails server regains the right again.

Anybody has an idea what's happening here? This is really annoying. I'm also only able to do `rake log:clear` as long as I didn't hit "save" for development.log, so it's exactly the same strange behavior...

I described a similar strange behavior like this before, and I suspected AckMate to have something to do with it. Sadly, I didn't get any response, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721159/textmate-find-in-files-seems-to-have-out-of-date-cache-maybe-because-of-ackmat).

Thanks a lot for help, this is really bugging me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vim` writes your file to a temporary file and then renames it.

The Rails process keeps writing to the old opened [fd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor).

Comment: This sounds interesting, but I'm still confused. What's an `fd`? And does TextMate the same? And why do I remember that some years ago, this didn't occur to me?

Comment: TextMate likely does the same.

Comment: Still: what's an fd? I don't really get the technical internals you are pointing at.

Comment: A file descriptor is a handle your application uses to access your file. You can even write to a deleted file if you have an fd open referencing it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing me into this direction, this sounds reasonable (though not very welcome). Still strange that in earlier days, this didn't seem to have been a problem.